# Is there a way to ignore EXIF orientation data when loading an image with PIL?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, python-imaging-library

I'm getting some unwanted rotation when loading images using PIL.  I'm loading image samples and their binary mask, so this is causing issues.  I'm attempting to convert the code to use openCV instead, but this is proving sticky.  I haven't seen any arguments in the documentation under Image.load(), but I'm hoping there's a workaround I just haven't found...

Answer (score 2):

Author's "much simpler solution" detailed in above comment is misleading so I just wanna clear that up.

- Pillow does not automatically apply EXIF orientation transformation when reading an image. However, it has a method to do so: [PIL.ImageOps.exif_transpose(image)](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageOps.html#PIL.ImageOps.exif_transpose)
- OpenCV automatically applies EXIF orientation when reading an image. You can disable this behavior by using the [IMREAD_IGNORE_ORIENTATION](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/d6a/group__imgcodecs__flags.html#gga61d9b0126a3e57d9277ac48327799c80af660544735200cbe942eea09232eb822) flag.

I believe the author's true intention was to *apply* the EXIF orientation rather than ignore it, which is exactly what his solution accomplished.

Answer (score 1):

There is, but I haven't written it all up. Basically, if you load an image with **EXIF** *"Orientation"* field set, you can get that parameter.

First, a quick test using this image from the PIL GitHub source `Pillow-7.1.2/Tests/images/hopper_orientation_6.jpg`  and run `jhead` on it you can see the EXIF orientation is 6:

```
jhead /Users/mark/StackOverflow/PillowBuild/Pillow-7.1.2/Tests/images/hopper_orientation_6.jpg
File name    : /Users/mark/StackOverflow/PillowBuild/Pillow-7.1.2/Tests/images/hopper_orientation_6.jpg
File size    : 4951 bytes
File date    : 2020:04:24 14:00:09
Resolution   : 128 x 128
Orientation  : rotate 90     <--- see here
JPEG Quality : 75
```

Now do that in PIL:

```
from PIL import Image

# Load that image
im = Image.open('/Users/mark/StackOverflow/PillowBuild/Pillow-7.1.2/Tests/images/hopper_orientation_6.jpg')                         

# Get all EXIF data
e = im.getexif()

# Specifically get orientation
e.get(0x0112)                                                                                                                       
# prints 6
```

Now click on the [source](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/PIL/ImageOps.html#exif_transpose) and you can work out how your image has been rotated and undo it.

---

Or, you could be completely unprofessional ;-) and create a function called `SneakilyRemoveOrientationWhileNooneIsLooking(filename)` and shell out (subprocess) to `exiftool` and remove the orientation with:

```
exiftool -Orientation=  image.jpg
```

Comment: This is super cool!  I actually found a much simpler solution.  It made me facepalm for not doing it earlier.  Basically, I load the image and the annotation in PIL and get the size of each.  If the sizes don't match, I load them in cv2 (which appears to ignore the EXIF data) and then overwrite them with cv2.imwrite().  Bam.  Problem solved!  Herp derp.