# How to rotate image to the normal position, if it's in 90, 180 or 270 degrees to normal using opencv

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have an image like this [which is in different position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEEsQ.jpg)

'https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEEsQ.jpg' is the image url. I want to rotate it to normal position. **I mean if image is in any position, it should rotate to the normal position**

**How to write a code to rotate the image to normal position.**

Comment: Will the image (in normal position) always have a wide aspect ratio? Will it always contain a face(s)?

Comment: No faces, it's a document. Like an invoice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using OpenCV, how can I detect text orientation before performing OCR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122635/using-opencv-how-can-i-detect-text-orientation-before-performing-ocr)

Comment: No, the code should check if it's in normal position or not. If it is not in normal position, then it should rotate to normal.

Comment: There is no direct way to solve this unless you are able to use the text orientation to understand which direction is your text going. Then use that to rotate.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to do that.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62029641/2836621 and https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html?highlight=Orientation%20#orientation